# Error running Google directory API

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine

I have a wrapper around the Google directory API that adds users to groups.

It works, at least for a while, but after perhaps 20 or 30 calls (let's say I'm updating 5 users, each one belonging to 5 groups, it doesn't take long to hit that number) it stops working with this error:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 980, in getresponse
raise ResponseNotReady()
httplib.ResponseNotReady
```

Here's the code it dies on:

`service = build('admin','directory_v1',http=http)`

If I wait for 1/2 hour, it works again, but only for a few calls then dies like before.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch) ? Are you using pagination? Can you please provide the rest of the code to see if your are doing something different?

Comment: Ack. It looks like the exact message above was a temporary problem from Google last week.

The issue still happens, but it appears to be in a different place:

    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/google_api_python_client-1.1-py2.6.egg/oauth2client/client.py       _do_refresh_request       710
    raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)
    invalid_request

Any ideas? It works for a few requests, then dies with this message.

Comment: I haven't tried batch requests, and I'm not using pagination. It shouldn't be required, since there's not a lot of data changing hands, it's just individual updates. I'd hate to re-engineer for batch, it would be a real pain.

Comment: Ok, the second error sounds like it's related with the OAuth token. The way I handle that is to set the approval_prompt in the OAuth2WebServerFlow as 'force' if there is no refresh token stored or 'auto' otherwise. See the [OAuth docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer)

Comment: Any idea how to do that through the python API?

Comment: Okay, I think I see how to do that with OAuth2WebServerFlow, but I'm using the SignedJwtAssertionCredentials. Is there a corollary?

Answer (score 0):

Rate limit quotes maybe? You can check this from the cloud console. Click APIs & Auth -> APIs -> Admin SDK -> Quotas. The default rate limit is 15.0 requests/second/user - if you are exceeding that you will need to use backoff logic.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not quotas, unless I'm looking at the wrong thing. I cranked it up to 500 requests/second/user and it's 150,000 requests a day.